# Python ctypes.string_at() adds surrounding b'...' in Python 3 (but not 2)

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I add Python bindings on top of my C++ library using `ctypes` (being more skilled in C++ than Python).

The C++ library needs to call back the application, becoming a Python callback. Using elementary types or structures works well. However, I have a weird issue with strings. After googling quite a lot, I realize that all online posts about `ctypes` carefully avoid passing strings to Python callbacks, as if it was a mine field. I couldn't find a working example of string passing to Python callbacks.

In short, when the C string "`foobar`" is passed to Python 2, the callback receives "`foobar`". But, in Python 3, it gets "`b'foobar'`" (note the extra `b'`...`'`).

Simple C++ library `foo.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void testLib(void *(*callback)(const char*, size_t))
{
    callback("foobar", 6);
}
```

Simple Python `test.py`:

```
import ctypes

def py_callback(buf, len):
    print("In py_callback(), len = %d, str = <%s>" % (len, ctypes.string_at(buf, len)))
   
callback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_size_t)
_lib = ctypes.CDLL('./libfoo.so')
_lib.testLib(callback(py_callback))
```

And `Makefile`:

```
CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
default: libfoo.so
libfoo.so: foo.o
        g++ $^ -shared -o $@
```

See the difference between Python 2.7.18 and 3.8.6:

```
$ make
g++ -fPIC   -c -o foo.o foo.cpp
g++ foo.o -shared -o libfoo.so
$ python2 test.py 
In py_callback(), len = 6, str = <foobar>
$ python3 test.py 
In py_callback(), len = 6, str = <b'foobar'>
```

Any idea on how to get a clean string in a Python `ctypes` callback without decoration with all Python implementations? Except explicitly looking for and removing the `b'`...`'` of course.

Comment: Do you understand what the `b` means?

Answer (score 2):

The value received is a byte string in both Python 2 and Python 3.  Python 3 displays byte string with the `b''` syntax by default to indicate it is a byte (data) string and not a Unicode (text) string.  If you want to process the `char*` as text, decode it from data bytes to text appropriately.  For example if the value represents a simple ASCII string:

```
>>> s = b'ascii string'
>>> print(s)
b'ascii string'
>>> print(s.decode('ascii'))
ascii string
```

`.decode()` takes an encoding and converts a byte string to a Unicode string.  Of course as mentioned in the other answer, you could pass a `wchar_t*` from C++ to the callback instead and ctypes will do the decoding for you with `ctypes.wstring_at`.

Another important point is ctypes will convert `c_char_p` to an actual Python `bytes` object and the address used by `string_at` is actually the buffer in the `bytes` object, which is copied from the pointer passed by C++ and stops at the first zero byte.  If your callback intends to modify the buffer and intend C++ to see the changes, or the data buffer contains zero bytes and needs to process the entire length, this won't work.

C demo code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*callback)(char*,size_t);

__declspec(dllexport)
void func(callback cb) {
    char data[] = {'a','b','c',0,'d','e','f'};
    if(cb)
        cb(data,sizeof data);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof data; ++i)
        printf("%c ",data[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Failing example with `c_char_p`:

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('./test')
CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(None,c_char_p,c_size_t)

@CALLBACK
def callback(s,size):
    print(string_at(s,size))
    s[0] = b'x'
    s[1] = b'y'
    s[size-1] = b'z'
    print(string_at(s,size))

dll.func.argtypes = CALLBACK,
dll.func.restype = None

dll.func(callback)
```

Note the byte string after the zero byte is incorrect, and you can't modify the buffer:

```
b'abc\x00\x8b\x01\x00'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 234, in 'calling callback function'
  File "C:\Users\metolone\test.py", line 9, in callback
    s[0] = b'x'
TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment
a b c   d e f
```

Passing example with `POINTER(c_char)` and added some display options:

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('./test')
CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(None,POINTER(c_char),c_size_t)

@CALLBACK
def callback(s,size):
    print(string_at(s,size))                  # display as bytes
    print(string_at(s,size).decode('ascii'))  # display as text
    print(string_at(s,size).hex())            # display as hexadecimal
    s[0] = b'x'
    s[1] = b'y'
    s[size-1] = b'z'
    print(string_at(s,size))

dll.func.argtypes = CALLBACK,
dll.func.restype = None

dll.func(callback)
```

Note the buffer is correct, can be modified, and C shows the change.

```
b'abc\x00def'                   # byte string display
abc def                         # text string display
61626300646566                  # hex string display
b'xyc\x00dez'
x y c   d e z
```

Comment: Thanks. Understood and fixed. As you have noticed, this was a typical question from a C++ guy being disconcerted by the exotic pythonic way :)

Answer (score 0):

The `b'...'` is [the syntax for a `bytes` literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-bytesliteral) and not part of the string, it's telling you that the "string" is actually a `bytes` object, not a `str`. Changing `%s` to `%r` in your format string shows this more clearly:

```
$ python3 test.py
In py_callback(), len = 6, str = <b'foobar'>
$ python2 test.py
In py_callback(), len = 6, str = <'foobar'>
```

There's not a perfectly reliable way to go from `char*` to `str` because the meaning of `str` has changed. In Python 3, `str` went from being a sequence of bytes to a unicode string (the python 2 `unicode` type).

You can get around it in several ways.

**Wrapper function for ctypes**

The conversion of `char*` will be perfectly consistent depending on which Python major version you have -- 3 will always have bytes, 2 will always have str -- so you can write a function that you call instead of `ctypes.string_at`.

```py
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    def c_string_at(buf, len):
        return ctypes.string_at(buf, len).decode()
else:
    c_string_at = ctypes.string_at
```

**Solve it in C++ by making your callback parameter `const wchar_t*`**

```cpp
extern "C" void testLib2(void *(*callback)(const wchar_t*, size_t))
{
    callback(L"foobar", 6);
}
```

```py
def py_callback(buf, count):
    value = ctypes.wstring_at(buf, count)
    print("In py_callback(), count = %d, str = <%s>, type = %s" % (
        count, value, type(value).__name__))

callback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_size_t)
_lib = ctypes.CDLL('./libfoo.so')
_lib.testLib2(callback(py_callback))
```

```
$ python2 test.py
In py_callback(), count = 6, str = <foobar>, type = unicode
$ python3 test.py
In py_callback(), count = 6, str = <foobar>, type = str
```